# How oauth works for saving users data?

Tags: django, oauth

I am building simple booking app in django, so flow of the app is that user's can do a booking and then their bookings will be saved into the database, However as I'll be using oatuh in my app, So my question is if user has made a booking and I want to fetch all of the bookings user's has made how do I implement this using oauth? what data of user data do I store in my own database so that each time user login using oauth I can fetch specifically that user's data (bookings).

Comment: OAuth2 only defines a protocol for authenticating a user and issuing a token as proof, it doesn't concern itself with storing other data.

Comment: Yeah that made sense but how does oath would help me save data that's related to a user eg -> some booking or a purchase that user has done. What kind of user information we would save in the database and upon oath login we would fetch that specific user's information. How do we relate user's data that's local to our database to oath. (I know that's somewhat confusing from to explain)

Comment: So for instance if I went to airbnb.com and signup using google oauth. and do some bookings there. So if we think about this how would airbnb save my bookings If I didn't provide any information about myself and only authenticate via google auth? That's my question. How would they store my bookings or what information they would store about me so every time I login using google auth they would know that it's me and fetch all of my bookings. (Hope this made sense)

Comment: OAuth2 alone does not do this. Usually OAuth2 services have a *different* API that lets you exchange the token you got for user information. The OAuth2 answer to this is called Token Introspection, but not everyone supports it and some services will have their own version of this.